# Load Testing Website Recommendation? Requires Login to get to Website to Test

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, allure, locust

I'm creating an Automated Testing Python Project to test a website. This Testing Project needs to perform Functionality, Accessibility and Load Testing of the website, and report the results. I'm coding the Project in **Python**, automating the code using **Selenium**, Accessibility Testing with **[axe](https://www.deque.com/axe/)** and reporting with **Allure Framework**. My OS of choice is Windows.

I'm feeling comfortable with the Functional and Accessibility Testing piece. However, I'm not sure what I should be using for Load Testing.

I've been recommended [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/), and I've setup a Test Plan. However, the website I'm testing requires Login through an intermediary Company Login Page before I can get to the homepage I need to test. **HTTP Post Request** doesn't work because there is no option (that I know of) for clicking a "Sign In" button (you can send `text/plain` Content, but not a button press action), and **HTTP Authorization Manager** doesn't work either because I think it only works for a pop-up login, not a whole HTML Login Page.

I've also looked into [Locust](https://locust.io/), which I thought would be nice because I could incorporate it inside my Python Project. However, I run into a similar situation as JMeter: `@task` doesn't look to be built to include any steps outside of connecting to the page (`self.client.get(url="")` for the homepage).

It might help if I share the Python Code for Login (also some functions for `access`, which handling Axe Accessibility Testing on a page, and `find_string` which I simply use to look to see if specific text can be found meaning I've connected to a page successfully), which works just fine when run with PyTest.

**website.py**

```
import allure
import sys
import time
from axe_selenium_python import Axe
from libraries.report import Report
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class Website:
    def __init__(self, browser: str, username: str, password: str):
        try:
            if browser == "Chrome":
                self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
            elif browser == "Edge":
                self.driver = webdriver.Edge()
        except:
            print("Only 'Chrome' and 'Edge' browsers are supported for testing.")
            sys.exit(1)
        
        self.driver.get("https://localhost/homepage")
        
        get_source = self.driver.page_source # Scan the page
        not_private1 = "Your connection is not private"
        not_private2 = "Your connection isn't private"
        if (not_private1 in get_source or not_private2 in get_source):
            # NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
            self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "details-button").click() # Click "Advanced" button
            self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);") # Scroll to the bottom of the page
            self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "proceed-link").click() # Click "Proceed to localhost (unsafe)" link
        
        get_source = self.driver.page_source # Redirects to Corporate Login Page
        login_page = "Login Page"
        if (login_page in get_source):
            self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "userNameInput").send_keys(username)
            self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "passwordInput").send_keys(password)
            self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "submitButton").click()
            time.sleep(1)

      # connects to the homepage

    def access(self, json: str):
        axe = Axe(self.driver)
        axe.inject() # Inject axe-core javascript into page.
        results = axe.run() # Run axe accessibility checks.
        axe.write_results(results, json) # Write results to file
        report = Report()

        if len(results["violations"]) == 0: # Assert no violations are found
            print("No Access Violations found on page!")
            report.screenshot_png(self.driver, "access: PASS")
            self.driver.close()
            assert True
            return True
        else:
            print("Access Violations found on page!")
            report.screenshot_png(self.driver, "access: FAIL")
            self.driver.close()
            assert False, axe.report(results["violations"]) # Reports violations found on page
            return False

    def find_string(self, search_text: str):
        get_source = self.driver.page_source # Scan the page
        report = Report()
        
        if (search_text in get_source):
            print("String Text '" + search_text + "' on page found!")
            report.screenshot_png(self.driver, "find_string: PASS")
            self.driver.close()
            assert True
            return True
        else:
            print("String Text '" + search_text + "' on page not found.")
            report.screenshot_png(self.driver, "find_string: FAIL")
            self.driver.close()
            assert False, "String Text '" + search_text + "' on page not found."
            return False
    
    def close(self):
        self.driver.close() # Closes the browser
```

I would also like to find a Load Test solution that I can also share the results in an Allure Report, like I've been able to so far with Functional and Accessibility Testing results (I have a separate file for generating the Allure Report).

Comment: In `locust` the `on_start` method should be the right place to implement the login functionality. How this implementation looks like depends on your authorization mechanism. If you, say, end up with a Bearer token that needs to be passed in a `Authorization` header, you can store this in the `client` attribute's headers: https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#client-attribute-httpsession

Comment: Didn't know about `on_start`, thank you. [However, I tried adding `on_start` to my Locust file, and it doesn't seem to have helped.](https://pastebin.com/9zZLbwfN) Keep in mind the `def __init__` in `website.py` works just fine, so I know the Login sequence is correct. Any suggestions for fixing up my `locust.py` file?

Comment: From what I see you are mixing up two things here:
`HttpUser.client` is a requests session. This is the one that is used in your tasks for making the request.
For the login procedure in `on_start` you are using the Selenium webdriver to log in. This will not affect the `HttpUser.client` in any way, therefore it has no effect.
If you want to continue the Locust approach, you probably have to find out what authentication mechanism your website is using (one *example* would be OpenID Connect), and implement the authentication flow yourself.

Comment: The Login Method is through a Company Domain outside of the Website I'm testing (if I try connecting to the site I'm testing, I'm automatically redirected to the Company Domain's Login Page, and I have to login EVERY time; only once I login am I redirected to the website I'm testing), which makes all of this even more complicated. An Administrator let me know that login is handled with a SAML Token. How can I get the SAML Token (the Admin hasn't been able to help with this) and how would I include it into Locust and my Python Code?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot help in detail with this. SAML has different protocols and bindings.
I think the best way forward would be to: 1. find out what your Identity Provider is (e.g. OKTA) 2. find out what protocol and bindings are used 3. with this more specific information try to find out how to implement the authentication flow.
Maybe one of these links can help you get started:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0
https://auth0.com/blog/how-saml-authentication-works/

Answer (score 0):

No matter which load testing tool you choose you will need to configure it appropriately to simulate the real browser's network footprint.

So it should look like (simplified):

1. [HTTP GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) request to the login page
2. [HTTP POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) request providing the credentials

Most probably you will also need to extract some dynamic data from the response and add it to the next request, the process is known as [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter) and there is a lot of information on it in the Internet. The most common example is HTTP Cookies which can be handled automatically by JMeter's [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager), but it doesn't handle everything.

So I would recommend recording your test scenario (starting from login) using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) twice and compare resulting test plans. All the parameters which differ are a subject to correlation. Once you perform the correlation you should be able to log in successfully.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. Let me share the setup of my current JMeter Test Plan as simply as I can in this Pastebin (with the important details): https://pastebin.com/UCyxLc88 Currently the only Response Assertion passing is the first (finding the "Login Page" text). The POST Request and subsequent GET Request Response Assertions Failed. I also tried adding the Test Script Recorder (and a Recording Controller before the POST Request on the Login Page), but I get an error (see same Pastebin). Is my JMeter Test Plan setup correct? What is causing the Test Script Error?